# How can you get two OpenAI custom GPTs to talk to each other?

Tags: gpt, openai

I’ve tried specifying the URL of one custom URL GPT in the creation of another custom GPT in an attempt to have a team of custom GPTs working together. That failed…

Has anyone found a way to get multiple custom GPTs to work together? I suspect looking into APIs might be needed…

Answer (score 3):

That is an interesting proposition.

The Schema field in the GPT configuration page could be another option to try, as I can verify that field works to call another Plugin (but have not tested with calling another GPT from it), by adding an "action."

I have gotten multiple plugins (via that action parameter) to work within the same GPT, by adding multiple actions (but not getting one GPT to call another, which is what I think you mean by them "working together."

Comment: Getting one GPT to call another is what I’m hoping to achieve. I’ll look at the schema field to see if I can get that to work with an action. Thank you for the idea, hopefully it works!  =)

Comment: I thought to add that It may be easier perhaps to just serve a Yaml/Json with the same underlying code from a server (along with the underlying configuration, akin to running a plugin), and then use that as an action in your GPT (I know GPTs can support up to 10 actions) hope that helps, cheers!